# Fixing UTF-8 encoded as ISO-8859-1

Tags: character-encoding

Say you have a file which contains both UTF-8 characters and UTF-8 characters there were once read by a program who thought they were ISO-8859-1. So you have things like "Ã©" instead of "é". How do you fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally came up with a single sed command that did the job for me :

```
LANG='' sed -re 's/(\xc3)\x83\xc2([\x80-\xbf])/\1\2/g'
```

It does not handle unicode code point 0xA0 to 0xBF, but it should be pretty easy to adapt for those.